# spring batch getting data from file and passing to procedure

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

For a Spring batch project, I need to get the date from a file and then I need to pass this date to a procedure and then run the procedure.

Then the result of the procedure must be written to a csv file.
I tried using listeners but couldn't do this.

Can anyone please tell how this can be achieved or if possible can you share any sample code in github.

Comment: This sounds like a typical read -> process -> write. Read the Spring Batch docs and try to come up with something of your own, this is what Spring Batch is for and its docs are really well written.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you will need to get the date from your file and store it in the `JobExecutionContext`. One of the most simple solution would be to create a custom `Tasklet` to read the text file and store the result `String` in the context via a `StepExecutionListener`

This tasklet takes a `file` parameter and stores the result string with the key `file.date` :

```
public class CustomTasklet implements Tasklet, StepExecutionListener {

    private String date;
    private String file;    

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {}

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("file.date", date);
    }

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

         // Read from file using FileUtils (Apache)
         date = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
    }

    public void setFile(String file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

Use it this way :

```
 <batch:step>
      <batch:tasklet>
            <bean class="xx.xx.xx.CustomTasklet">
                <property name="file" value="${file.path}"></property>
            </bean>
        </batch:tasklet>
 </batch:step>
```

Then you will use a `Chunk` with late binding to retrieve the previously stored value (i.e. using `#{jobExecutionContext['file.date']}`).

The reader will be a `StoredProcedureItemReader` :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="procedureName" value="${procedureName}" />
    <property name="fetchSize" value="50" />
    <property name="parameters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="#{jobExecutionContext['file.date']}" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="rowMapper" ref="rowMapper" />
    <property name="preparedStatementSetter" ref="preparedStatementSetter" />
</bean>
```

The writer will be a `FlatFileItemWriter` :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="${file.dest.path}" />
    <property name="lineAggregator" ref="lineAggregator" />
</bean>
```